# Concatenate multiple columns into one with dplyr

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a df structured like this, but with a large number of columns and rows:

```
 A   B   C   D 
 1   4   3   3
```

and I want to obtain a df with a single column, made by the concatenation of all the previous elements:

```
 A
 1
 B
 4
 C
 3
 D
 3
```

How can I do?
Better if solutions comprise the use of dplyr.

Comment: How about `unlist`?

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` column names ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unlist` and wrap it in `data.frame`

```
data.frame(col = unlist(df), row.names = NULL)

#  col
#1   A
#2   1
#3   B
#4   4
#5   C
#6   3
#7   D
#8   3
```

---

Or making it as `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
tibble(col = unlist(df))

#   col  
#  <fct>
#1   A    
#2   1    
#3   B    
#4   4    
#5   C    
#6   3    
#7   D    
#8   3
```

---

Another option mentioned by @Sotos is `stack` but it needs columns of class characters

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
stack(df)[1]
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "A   B   C   D 
                         1   4   3   3")
```

Comment: or `stack(df)[1]`...assuming that A, B, ... are not colnames

Comment: @Sotos I get error: `Error in stack.data.frame(df) : no vector columns were selected` ? :/

Comment: convert to character first. You probably have factors

Answer (score 2):

In `tidyverse`, use `gather`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df) %>% 
     select(value)
```